# C Compiler in Code::Blocks Fails on Unfound .h File Even Though It Has File in Directory

Tags: c, file, codeblocks

This has to be a noob error, but I can't find it.

Using CodeBlocks and the compiler quits since it can't find a particular file ( resource.h ).  That file is in the directory structure (pic on Imgur here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXgwD.jpg since I'm also new to stackoverflow)

I can't be the first person to make this mistake, but can't get any farther with it.  My guess is that it won't find the other header files that follow in the list either.

Suggestions?

---

@ace and others have it - it's the path that needs to be included in the code.  On to other errors...thanks everyone.

Comment: But it isn't in the same folder. It is in a folder called `res`, while your source file is in a folder called `src`. You have to either add `res` to the include path or add more of the path in the include statement.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

1. Change the `#include` line to

   ```
   #include "../res/resource.h"
   ```

   Here, the two dots `..` mean the parent directory.
2. Include the path of the directory when compiling

   ```
   gcc -I../res ./winmain.c
   ```

   This tells the compiler to search in `../res` for header files. Since you are using CodeBlocks you may have to do this via some settings. See the [CodeBlocks FAQ](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ-Compiling_%28general%29#Q:_I_would_like_to_compile_a_project_using_some_non-standard_libraries._How_can_I_indicate_to_CodeBlocks_that_these_libraries_and_include_files_exist.3F) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem once, but I'm not sure, if the solution also applies to you.

I added all files in my project structure to my project with Project->Add Files.